# How to solve this differential equation with power 2 and trigonometry?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$\ddot{x} = (\tan x) \dot{x}^2$

Do I have to use power series?

Comment: Are you sure you have written it correctly ?

Answer (score 2):

HINT: Divide by $\dot x$ and integrate,
$$
\int\frac{\ddot x}{\dot x}\,dt=\int \dot x\tan x\,dt.
$$

I think you can take it from that hint? Tell me otherwise, and I will give a first step.